# How to compare two statistical distributions with unavailability measurements?

Tags: inference, descriptive-statistics, exponential-distribution

I have two different measuring instruments to evaulate if an electronic device is working or not. These instruments provide a working/not-working reading each day and at the end of the month I compute the un-availability in the month for each component.

Since the number of components is fairly big (more than 30K) I have a lot of data.
Two points (% un-availability, one per measuring instrument) per component.

If you want to have a look at the raw data, please feel free to [download it here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xxaES-aLCnhydWmFyoSOvSlh1QL5pgq6).

Apparently, these availability measures have an Exponential distribution.
However, I tried a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test for goodness of fit using [Scipy with Python](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.kstest.html):

```
from scipy import stats
stats.kstest(x, 'expon')
```

But this test is failing for both the measuring instruments with a p-value of 0.

Since plotting the frequency histogram of this data is a little bit tricky (because most of the values are very close to zero), I'm a little bit confused on how to deal with it.

The questions I would like to answer are:

1. Which is the statistical distribution that better describes the data (if any) or how to identify a set of observations that are outside this distribution;
2. If the two set of observations are coming from the same statistical population; that is, the two measuring instruments can be considered equivalent.